# image/Text with url behind in RTB in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am going through the development of a chat app in `WinForms`/`C#`. I have used a `RichTextBox` for the chat messages. What now I need actually is to send a screenshot with the chat text. For this I need to send an image with chat text so that user can click on the image and see the screenshot. Said image will be stored on server.

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(btn1.BackgroundImage);
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(img);
DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
rtbWriteMsg.Paste(myFormat);
img.Dispose();
rtbWriteMsg.Focus();
```

I have an idea to use the image in `RichTextBox` with the above code but how can I make it linked with some url? I need some ideas. .

Update:
If I can also get help if anyone give me an idea to put the linked text in `RichTextBox`just like "Click Here To View". So user can Click on it and View the ScreenShot

Comment: I'm confused - are you storing a history of the chat as an image? Or is this an image that you are sending to someone else via IRC or something? Or is this just a screen shot of the current window for some other purpose?

Comment: i just want to send the screen shot that been stored on my server with my another application , i want to send that screen shot with chat text by getting the path from the server.... i can get all things but stuck here ... how can i put in rtb ... so that user can click on the image and can see the screenshot